# Making authorization in Wcf Data service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, authorization, wcf-data-services

I'm writting **WCF REST Data Service**. I need to add authorization system basing on login and password given by url addres(https).

In every url should be login and password:

```
https://myservice.svc/Products()?$orderby=name&login=user_login&pass=user_pass
```

And on the service side **I want to make authorization**. There should be checked if user has **permission to access** the **data**. In this scenario there should checked if user has Role to read table Products. **The Roles are stored in database**.

Is there any opportunity to make it?

Comment: I'm sure you have opportunity to make it but I question the wisdom of including the username and password in the url. WCF provides you with a bunch of ways of authenticating callers. What's wrong with them?

Comment: Hey, it nothing wrong with them, but I need more complexity functionality. This example above is only a sample which can help me solve my problem.

Comment: Won't putting the password in the URL make it entirely insecure and defeat the point of using https? Instead you should consider putting the login details as a post content in your service.. or just use HTTP Basic Authentication

Answer (score 0):

Implement OnStartProcessingRequest method.

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
    [ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
    public class ServiceODataAFR : EntityFrameworkDataService<PortalContext>
    {
        public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
        {
            ValidarAcesso();

            config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V3;
            config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.AllRead);
        }

        protected override void OnStartProcessingRequest(ProcessRequestArgs args)
        {
            ValidarAcesso();

            base.OnStartProcessingRequest(args);
        }

        private static void ValidarAcesso()
        {
            using (var context = new PortalWeb())
            {
                if (!context.UsuarioEstaNoGrupo(EnumGrupoPermissao.AdministradorAFR.GetTitle()))
                {
                    throw new AddressAccessDeniedException();
                }
            }
        }
```